# Frida: Replace string literal in class method

Tags: frida

I ran an APK through `dex2jar` and `JD-GUI` and found the class I'm interested in:

```java
public class RESTClient {
    ....
    private bdG.\u0269 \u02CB\u0971() {
        return (new bdG.\u0269()).\u02CA((new bdq.if()).\u0971("www.google.com", new String[] { "sha256/asdIa1tHg96AnzarJ6GJLu6JiogJla3UDsPWMDICs=" }).\u02CE()).\u02CE((bdF)\u02BD\u0971()).\u02CB((bdv)\u02BC\u0971());
    }
}
```

I've been trying to use Frida to replace the `sha256/...` string but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Here's what I've done:

```js
Java.perform(function() {
    var StringBuilder = Java.use('java.lang.StringBuilder');
    StringBuilder.$init.overload('java.lang.String').implementation = function(str) {
        return this.$init.call(this, str);
    }
    StringBuilder.toString.implementation = function() {
        var result = this.toString.call(this);
        if(result == "sha256/asdIa1tHg96AnzarJ6GJLu6JiogJla3UDsPWMDICs=") {
            console.log("[x] Found and replaced!");
            return "sha256/somethingelsegoeshere";
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

While this code does match, the returned string doesn't appear to have any effect. How can I find and replace the string in memory directly?

EDIT: Including `jadx` output too:

```java
private C9575bdG.C4644 m708() {
    return new C9575bdG.C4644().m73741(new C9612bdq.Cif().m74142("www.google.com", "sha256/asdIa1tHg96AnzarJ6GJLu6JiogJla3UDsPWMDICs=").m74141()).m73751((C9574bdF) m695()).m73747((C9617bdv) m694());
}
```

EDIT: Including smali output from `apktool`:

```
.method private ˋॱ()Lo/bdG$ɩ;
    .locals 6

    .prologue
    .line 99
    new-instance v0, Lo/bdG$ɩ;

    invoke-direct {v0}, Lo/bdG$ɩ;-><init>()V

    new-instance v1, Lo/bdq$if;

    invoke-direct {v1}, Lo/bdq$if;-><init>()V

    const-string v2, "www.google.com"

    const/4 v3, 0x1

    new-array v3, v3, [Ljava/lang/String;

    const/4 v4, 0x0

    const-string v5, "sha256/asdIa1tHg96AnzarJ6GJLu6JiogJla3UDsPWMDICs="

    aput-object v5, v3, v4

    .line 100
    invoke-virtual {v1, v2, v3}, Lo/bdq$if;->ॱ(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lo/bdq$if;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Lo/bdq$if;->ˎ()Lo/bdq;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lo/bdG$ɩ;->ˊ(Lo/bdq;)Lo/bdG$ɩ;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 101
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/target/android/data/remote/RESTClient;->ʽॱ()Lo/bfa;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lo/bdG$ɩ;->ˎ(Lo/bdF;)Lo/bdG$ɩ;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 102
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/target/android/data/remote/RESTClient;->ʼॱ()Lo/qz;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lo/bdG$ɩ;->ˋ(Lo/bdv;)Lo/bdG$ɩ;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 99
    return-object v0
.end method
```

Comment: The String "sha256/..." is a constant string. Constant strings are not generated via StringBuilder, so why do you hook StringBuilder? IMHO you should hook the method `\u0971` which gets the String array containing this string as second parameter. In that hook you can replace the string.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on hooking the `\u0971` method. What would the full package name be for the class this method belongs to?

Comment: I don't know, your code sample is too small. In any way dex2jar + DJGui is not a good combination for getting details for Frida (dex is register based, Java is stack based conversion between both system introduces many errors). I prefer apktool for getting smali (you would have seen there that no StringBuilder is involved) or Jadx for Java decompilation.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the tip. I imagined it'd possible to discern from the `return` statement that invokes that method call, right? At any rate, I've edited the question to include `jadx` output for the method too.

Comment: For Jadx you need to disable the deobfuscation/renaming options in the settings. In any way you need the full class names. hence code snipets won't work here. Use the smali code it alsways uses the full class names.

Comment: @Robert So smali always maps exactly to the class names I'd need to use in Frida? I've included `apktool` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call in Java:
`.\u0971("www.google.com", new String[] {"sha256/asdIa1tHg96AnzarJ6GJLu6JiogJla3UDsPWMDICs=" })`
is found in smali at:
`invoke-virtual {v1, v2, v3}, Lo/bdq$if;->ॱ(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lo/bdq$if;`

The Java class is `o.bdq$if` (class `if` is nested inside `o.bdq`). The method name is `ॱ`

```js
Java.perform(function() {
  var ObfuscatedClass = Java.use('o.bdq$if');
  ObfuscatedClass.ॱ.implementation = function(string, stringArray) { // replace original implementation
    var modifiedStringArray = ...; // do your stuff with the stringArray that contains your hash
    return this.ॱ(string, modifiedStringArray); // call original method with modified string array containing new hash
  }
});
```